# List index out of range error when canceling filechooser in Kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, firebase, kivy, kivymd

I tried to make this video uploading app to my firebase storage, but I'm stuck at this problem. When the upload button is pressed, the filechooser is opened and if i select a file, it gets uploaded to firebase. But if i cancel and close the filechooser, it gives an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\Dheeraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\plyer\platforms\win\filechooser.py",
> line 108, in run self._handle_selection(self.selection) File
> "C:\Users\Dheeraj\Desktop\kivy codes\Dheeraj.py", line 949, in
> selected Directory=selection[0] IndexError: list index out of range
> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

I am unaware if this file chooser works on android or not. If it does not, please help me with this code too.

#### Versions

- OS: win 7 pro
- Python: 3.7
- Kivy: latest
- KivyMD: latest (update everyweek)

#### Code

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
import json
from plyer import filechooser
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
import requests
import pyrebase
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds, RewardedListenerInterface
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty,BooleanProperty
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
import re
from kivy.garden.notification import Notification
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import FakeRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
import plyer

help_str='''
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'mainscreen'

    MDFloatLayout:
        id:floate

        Video:
            id:vid

        MDRaisedButton:
            id:upload
            text:'Upload'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.05}
            on_release:
                app.file_chooser()
                upload.disabled=True


'''
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'mainscreen'))

class LoginApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.strng = Builder.load_string(help_str)
        self.url  = "**confidential**.json"
        return self.strng

    def file_chooser(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)        
    def selected(self,selection):
        configure={
            'apiKey': "**confidential**",
            'authDomain': "**confidential**",
            'databaseURL': "**confidential**",
            'projectId': "**confidential**",
            'storageBucket': "**confidential**",
            'messagingSenderId': "**confidential**",
            'appId': "**confidential**",
            'measurementId': "**confidential**",
            'serviceAccount':"**confidential**",
            'databaseURL':'**confidential**' 

                      }
        firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(configure)
        storage=firebase.storage()            
        Directory=selection[0]
        Name=re.findall('[ \w-]+\..*',Directory)
        storage.child(str(f"{Name}")).put(str(f"{Name[0]}"))

        if selection==true:
            self.root.ids.vid.source=firebase

if __name__=="__main__":
    LoginApp().run()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `android`?

Comment: Kivymd is a platform to build apps with python for android and ios..... please help me.

Comment: There are many dependencies in your code, try removing them and post only the [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that raised the error.

Comment: i have done it sir....please help

Comment: Your posted code does not run at all.

Comment: @JohnAnderson sir i've changed the code but it requires the api keys to solve the first error of uploading...but the issue is it does not give error on uploading in actual code, on canceling it gives this||||Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Dheeraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\plyer\platforms\win\filechooser.py", line 108, in run self._handle_selection(self.selection) File "C:\Users\Dheeraj\Desktop\kivy codes\Dheeraj.py", line 949, in selected Directory=selection[0] IndexError: list index out of range|||

Comment: @JohnAnderson sir please help,please 

Comment: @ApuCoder sir please help now, please 

Comment: @dheeraj It's really hard to find the error when the code contains some incomplete (or unknown) description about a packages/module etc. and does not run properly (perhaps due to this). That's why a minimal runnable program is expected. However is it possible to use `MDFileManager` in your code and later set a requirement for external storage write permission ? That way I think, you will have more control over manipulation of file tree.

Comment: @ApuCoder sir can you please make some changes in code 2. so that when i select a video file(only) from directory it gets uploaded to firebase storage. please .like when i select a file that should point as the source of the video file self.root.ids.vid.source

Answer (score 0):

i think i've figured it out
all i have to do was indent the code of selected function under its own if selection==True statement.
thanks to everyone who tried to help .

#### New Code

```
def selected(self,selection):
    
    if selection==true:
        self.root.ids.vid.source=firebase
        configure={
        'apiKey': "**confidential**",
        'authDomain': "**confidential**",
        'databaseURL': "**confidential**",
        'projectId': "**confidential**",
        'storageBucket': "**confidential**",
        'messagingSenderId': "**confidential**",
        'appId': "**confidential**",
        'measurementId': "**confidential**",
        'serviceAccount':"**confidential**",
        'databaseURL':'**confidential**' 

                  }
    firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(configure)
    storage=firebase.storage()            
    Directory=selection[0]
    Name=re.findall('[ \w-]+\..*',Directory)
    storage.child(str(f"{Name}")).put(str(f"{Name[0]}"))
```